# Override a config.properties in a jar

Tags: java, jar, properties

I have executable jar file with its main class being specified in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and one some of the properties specified in `config.properties` and `folder/config.properties`.

So the structure of my jar file is

```
./my-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|- com/mypackage/Main.class
|- META_INF/MANIFEST.MF 
|- config.properties
|- folder
|    |- config.properties
|     - system.properties
|- lib
|
..
```

What I want to achieve is execute the jar file as `java -jar my-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dconfig.properties=\path\to\new\config.properties_outside_the_jar` and overriding the properties file within the jar.

Is this possible? If so how?

Note: I am not the one in control of how the jar is packaged, so changing the packaging of jar is not really an easy option

Comment: That can only work if the code was written to allow you to do such a thing.  If not, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Just put a directory containing the properties files, with the same package structure, in the classpath, before the jar file:

```
./my-config-directory
|- config.properties
|- folder
     |- config.properties
      - system.properties
```

And use

```
java -cp ./my-config-directory:my-jar-with-dependencies.jar:dependency1.jar:dependency2.jar com.mypackage.Main
```

Note that a jar file is just a zip file. So you could also just unzip the jar file, replace the properties files, and zip again.

Comment: Changing and repackaging the jar is not an option if the contents are signed with a certificate you don't have access to